# Magento 2.3: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: magento2.3

I have an error in my admin configuration when viewing Payment Methods section which only appears when I enable the `Amazon_Core` module which prevents me from being able to save settings for my payment methods:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getData (main.js:58)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.apply (main.js:74)
    at HTMLDocument.bootstrap (bootstrap.js:106)
    at fire (jquery.js:3232)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
    at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:241)
```

If I disable the `Amazon_Core` module, this error goes away and the admin payment method section works as expected.

Any ideas how to trouble shoot this error?

Ultimately, we're needing to be able to use the Amazon Login & Payment modules.  What's odd is this error is not present in our local environment, only on our live server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured this out, our store name had a apostrophe in it which was causing the error:
https://github.com/amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin/issues/428#issuecomment-470570367

Here is the fix:

File:
`vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module/Model/Config/SimplePath.php`

Replace Line: 487

```
'merchantStoreDescription' => $this->getConfig('general/store_information/name'),
```

with:

```
'merchantStoreDescription' => htmlspecialchars($this->getConfig('general/store_information/name'), ENT_QUOTES),
```

Comment: just came across this issue.  Thanks for posting :)