# Magento 2.3.1 JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 2 column 1009

Tags: magento2, composer, json

I am unable to set payment method in Magento 2.3.1.

As soon as I click on the payment method button all JavaScript functions are killed.

open error log nothing to show, but browser console point me to the [image] on line 51 to 60

**Please see image below for further explanation:**

[image]
My question is which file is generating the array in Core files. Or any idea of how to fix this.

Comment: this might be related to this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270795/magento-2-3-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-json-input?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @magefms This is correct thank you so much